# chmod +x not working as expected, running another tool instead

Tags: macos, command-line, zsh, swift

Just wrote a simple commandline tool which works fine with `swift` but doesn't run as executable after `chmod +x ...`

This is happening on my system so might be configuration related but not sure how to resolve.

---

##### Create Script:

```
vi test.swift
```

##### Enter content:

```
import Foundation
print("Hello, World!")
```

Running normally `swift test.swift` gives `Hello, World!` as expected but when I make it executable & run it then it's failing.

##### Make Executable:

```
chmod +x test.swift
./test.swift
```

##### Output:

```
Version: ImageMagick 7.1.0-52 Q16-HDRI aarch64 20549 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: (C) 1999 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI Modules OpenMP(5.0) 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib fontconfig freetype gslib heic jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr png ps raw tiff webp xml zlib
Compiler: gcc (4.2)
Usage: import [options ...] [ file ]

Image Settings:
  -adjoin              join images into a single multi-image file
  <redacted as unnecessary>

By default, 'file' is written in the MIFF image format.  To
specify a particular image format, precede the filename with an image
format name and a colon (i.e. ps:image) or specify the image type as
the filename suffix (i.e. image.ps).  Specify 'file' as '-' for
standard input or output.
import: delegate library support not built-in '' (X11) @ error/import.c/ImportImageCommand/1297.
./test.swift: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `"Hello, World!"'
./test.swift: line 3: `print("Hello, World!")'
```

Why is it running commandline tool `imagemagick`?

Comment: Does cat ./test.swift show the file expected?

Comment: @mmmmmm Yes, `cat` outputs the contents as expected.

Comment: Also, your `test.swift` is lacking a #! line. You need it when you want to run the program as `./test.swift`. Therefore, the external command `import` is executed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that the shell that runs the script does not know what program to run test.swift through.

In scripts you either need to run the program with the file as an argument e.g.

```
swift test.swift
```

or tell the shell what the program to run is in the script. This is done by a hash bang line beginning with #! Thus the script should be:

```swift
#! /usr/bin/swift
import Foundation
print("Hello, World!")
```

Comment: Oh man! This was clearly a miss from my side. Thanks for highlighting this. Much appreciated.